# Force a non-blocking UDP socket to raise BlockingIOError on sendto

Tags: python, linux, sockets, udp, nonblocking

I believe that a non-blocking UDP socket can raise a BlockingIOError on sendto. I would like to force this situation to test how my program behaves in this case.

```py
sock = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setblocking(False)
sock.bind(('', 7777))
...
# Even if repeating in a loop, doesn't seem to raise a BlockingIOError
sock.sendto(b'abcde', ('1.2.3.4', 61908))
```

I have tried setting the outgoing buffer small by

```
buffer_size = 5
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, buffer_size)
```

But it either seems to have no impact, or results in `OSError: [Errno 40] Message too long` if the buffer is smaller than the data.

Is my belief wrong: can it *never* raise a BlockingIOError? Or if it can, how can I force it?

My aim here is to have an integration-style test: I want to actually have a real socket and make actual network calls. Mocking the socket for a unit-style test in this case would not be ideal.

The socket will only be used from a single-threaded Python asyncio program.

Comment: Just keep sending as fast as you can until it happens, if ever. Either the network is fast enough to keep up with you or it isn't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From TCP/IP Sockets in C: Practical Guide for Programmers, Michael J. Donahoo, Kenneth L. Calvert

> For UDP sockets, there are no send buffers, so `send()` and `sendto()` never return `EWOULDBLOCK`

And from https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto there is a hint as to why...

> Packets are just silently dropped when a device queue overflows.

So in Python terms, `BlockingIOError` cannot be raised, at least on Linux.

Comment: That is contrary to to all my experience over merely 30 years, and to Comer, Stevens & Wright, and any number of more respected authors.

Comment: And specifically if there is no send buffer it would be impossible to get EMSGSIZE if the datagram is larger than the send buffer, and it isn't impossible.